# Logitech M325 mouse horizontal scrolling

Tags: fedora, mouse, scrolling

Out of the box, this Logitech M325 mouse works great with one issue: cannot use the scroll wheel for horizontal scrolling. It acts as forward or back in the browsers or does nothing in other windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make the horizontal scrolling work, I had to remap the mouse buttons. Check the mapping using `xmodmap -pp`:

```
[sly@SlyLap ~]$ xmodmap -pp
There are 24 pointer buttons defined.

    Physical        Button
     Button          Code
        1              1
        2              2
        3              3
        4              4
        5              5
        6              6
        7              7
        8              8
        9              9
       10             10
       11             11
       12             12
       13             13
       14             14
       15             15
       16             16
       17             17
       18             18
       19             19
       20             20
       21             21
       22             22
       23             23
       24             24
```

Use `xev` to find out the button codes for horizontal scrolling:

```
[sly@SlyLap ~]$ xev
...
ButtonPress event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0xad, subw 0x5400002, time 173143560, (21,37), root:(25,493),
    state 0x0, button 8, same_screen YES
...
ButtonPress event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0xad, subw 0x5400002, time 173126732, (21,37), root:(25,493),
    state 0x0, button 9, same_screen YES
```

From here I can see the left/right button codes are 8/9. Since the `synaptics` driver uses the buttons 6/7 for left/right scrolling, I simply needed to swap the order of how the buttons are declared. To change the mapping:

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 6 7 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24"
```

This will swap 8/9 6/7 which will make the horizontal scrolling work.

Comment: This is the easiest and most straightforward way to remap mouse buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Using xmodmap resulted in problems with sideways scrolling using the touchpad on my laptop. I got the M325 mouse working as expected, but the touchpad sideways scrolling was changed to Back/Forward.

To remap mouse buttons only (leaving the touchpad alone) I used the instructions in https://askubuntu.com/questions/492744/how-do-i-automatically-remap-buttons-on-my-mouse-at-startup

I saved the following script as ~/logitechM325

```
#!/bin/bash
# Swap buttons 8 9 with buttons 6 7 -- Sideways scrolling with Logitech M325
logitech_mouse_id=$(xinput | grep "Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a" | awk {'print substr($8,4,2)'})
echo $logitech_mouse_id > ~/temp/logitech_mouse_id
echo $logitech_mouse_id
xinput set-button-map $logitech_mouse_id 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 6 7 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

I made sure the script was executable:

```
$ sudo chmod a+x ~/logitechM325
```

and then added it to the list of Startup Applications.

Now both the Logitech M325 and the touchpad work for sideways scrolling.