# How to increase horizontal mouse scroll sensitivity?

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, kde, mouse, scrolling

I have a Logitech MX Master mouse with a vertical and horizontical scroll wheel. Everything works fine, mouse events work / can be remapped, both scroll wheels do their job, etc.
The only annoying thing is that horizontal scrolling is very slow and thus nearly useless...

So how can I adjust the scroll wheel sensitivity for the horizontal scroll wheel?

I have tried quite a lot of options with no luck:

- `solaar` does not provide any additional settings.
- xinput has a scrolling related setting `Evdev Scrolling Distance`, but it did not seem to change more than the scrolling direction.
- Neither did the xconf setting `HorizResolution` change the scrolling behavior (like suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/460594/418057)).
- As I found out with `xev`, the scroll wheel triggers button click events (buttons 6 and 7). So I tried a `xbindkeys` binding that triggers the button click three times again (using `xdotool`). This obviously resulted in a infinite loop of event → trigger → event → trigger → ... bringing the xserver to 100% CPU. No sleep delays or similar helped...
- None of the [XF86 keyboard symbols](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/x11proto/tree/XF86keysym.h) seems to represent vertical scrolling → no luck with remapping button 6/7 to a XF86 keyboard event.

Any ideas how to get the horizontal mouse scrolling faster? I'd be glad about help!

My system: Linux Mint 18 (based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), KDE Plasma 5.8.5

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I suddenly had an idea that solved this issue:

1) Remap the "buttons" associated with horizontal scroll from 6/7 to the unused ids 10/11 with `xinput` to avoid the recursive infinity loop. Call this from `~/.profile` or similar (inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165448/119183)):

```
#!/bin/bash
# improve Logitech MX Master horizontal scroll sensitivity
logitech_mouse_id=$(xinput | grep "Logitech MX Master" | sed 's/.*id=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/')
xinput set-button-map $logitech_mouse_id 1 2 3 4 5 10 11 8 9
```

2) Trigger repeated horizontal scrolling events with `xdotool`. Settings in `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
# thumb wheel up => scroll left
"xdotool click --repeat 10 --delay 1 6"
   b:10

# thumb wheel down => scroll right
"xdotool click --repeat 10 --delay 1 7"
   b:11
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks for sharing. I added a little if statement in the .profile code, so that weird things cannot happen when the mouse is not plugged in.

Comment: Based upon the idea above, I wrote a libevdev client which listens at a lower level for horizontal scroll wheel events and repeats them.  It's under the GPL: [evwheelmult](https://bstern.org/evwheelmult/).

Comment: awk-fu not needed as this works `xinput set-button-map 'Logitech MX Master' 1 2 3 4 5 10 11 8 9`

Comment: I'd clean up & merge that `grep | sed` command: `logitech_mouse_id=$(xinput | sed -nr 's/.*Logitech M.*id=([0-9]+).*/\1/p')`

Answer (score 3):

Solution that doesn't require button remappings, that worked for me, though I'm not on Mint, I'm using Ubuntu and Logitech MX Master 3 mouse.

1. Find your mouse by probing `cat /sys/class/input/event3/device/name`,  try different numbers after `event`, it was `3` in my case. Remember the result name.
2. Create file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/99-mx3-click-angle.hwdb` (you can pick another name, just make it start with 99).
3. The content of the file:

```
mouse:*:name:Logitech MX Master 3000:
  MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE_HORIZONTAL=10
```

Put the name of your device that you got on the 1st stage instead of my `Logitech MX Master 3000`.

4. update the hwdb:

```
sudo udevadm hwdb -u
```

5. Disconnect and reconnect your mouse.
6. To verify that the attribute was added run

```
> udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/input/event3 | grep MOUSE_WHEE

E: MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE_HORIZONTAL=10
```

here use your number from stage 1 instead of my event`3`.

---

Play with different values for `MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE_HORIZONTAL`, 10 works best for me.

There are also [other parameters to tune](https://github.com/whot/systemd/blob/master/hwdb/70-mouse.hwdb#L49). I'm adjusting the vertical scroll speed with `MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE=2`, for example, because my Logitech MX Master 3 was scrolling too fast on default settings.

Based on [this](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/issues/158#issuecomment-333737178) comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post in my searching for a solution. I wanted to pass it on to help anyone in the future:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=79002

Scroll down to *Sept 2017, 22:39* by *WombatFromHell*

This worked perfectly for me. I am running VirtualBox 5.1.30 r118389 and Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64Bit All credit goes to **WombatFromHell** on that post. I just wanted to pass it along. For me the file is `90-libinput.conf` but everything else is the same.

If you don't want to go to that page the solution is to edit a file at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`look for a file with `XX-libinput.conf` where XX could be 40 as in the original post or for me it was 90.

**important** you need to make sure you have the evdev driver installed. For me, it was already installed.

There are three `Section` blocks in my file. Find the one with `Identifier "libinput pointer cachall"` The last line of that block is `Driver "libinput"` change it to `Drive "evdev"` and reboot the guest.

I cannot offer advice if this doesn't work because I didn't come up with the solution I am just wanting to pass it along as a solution/workaround.